# PHP Unit Assert of response that contains how to

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, phpunit

Attempting to write unit testing for some ui validation messages that come back formatted like the following and completely lost

```
Unprocessable Content
Cache-Control: no-cache, private
Content-Type:  application/json
Date:          Fri, 31 Dec 2021 15:55:48 GMT

{"errors":{"assets":["filename must have a value"],"questions":[],"targeting_sets":[],"lists":[]}}
```

there error response gets generated using the following function

```
private function errorResponse()
{
    return response()->json([
        'errors' => $this->errors,
    ], Response::HTTP_UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY);
}
```

Would appreciate any help with how to properly write the test so if it response has `filename must have a value` it will pass

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to check if the session has a specific error using the [`assertSessionHasErrors`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/http-tests#assert-session-has-errors) method.

```php
$response->assertSessionHasErrors([
    'assets' => 'filename must have a value'
]);
```

As other comments have pointed out: you are returning a custom json response. That means that the method above will not work. Use [`assertJsonPath`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/http-tests#assert-json-path) instead.

```
$response->assertJsonPath("errors.assets", "filename must have a value");
```

As matiaslauriti suggested, the best-practise to do validation in Laravel is through a [`FormRequest`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#form-request-validation) or [`Validator`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#quick-writing-the-validation-logic). That will also allow you to write your unit tests in a less-complicated manner.

Comment: Given the lack of code in the question, it's unclear if the session is populated by the controller code. Your answer would be correct if dealing with standard Laravel validation, but not necessarily in this case. `assertJsonPath()` would be the more prudent choice here. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/http-tests#assert-json-path

Comment: I am very new to both laravel and unit testing neither of the mentioned `assert` methods work for me is just get `Call to undefined method `  assuming something isn't configured correctly with the model

Comment: @miken32 it is correct to use `assertSessionHasErrors`, the default way of solving validation is to use the [`Validator`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#validation-quickstart) or a [`FormRequest`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#form-request-validation) (uses `Validator` behind scenes). If the user is using other stuff, it is not our issue and he should clarify it. Every Laravel developer would expect to see/have/use a `Validator` whatever your implementation is.